# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined, but function accepts a class I made with defined toString() method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

HTML File

```
<form #jobForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(jobForm)">
  <div class="container" mt-3>
    <h5><b>From</b> Section</h5>
//...code

       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="typeahead-focus">Assign to:</label>
          <input
            id="typeahead-focus"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="jobAttributes[7]"
            [ngbTypeahead]="search"
            (focus)="focus$.next($any($event).target.value)"
            (click)="click$.next($any($event).target.value)"
            #instance="ngbTypeahead"
            name="jobAttributes[7]"
            required
          />
        </div>
```

TypeScript File. Please excuse the messy code. I refactor I promise. In the function onSubmit last param and jobAttributes[7] both are Employees. However when I call the toString, it is type of undefined, however when I look at the console it clearly says Employee and its characteristics. I would hate to extract the information and create a new employee. I have thought of possibly grabbing the employee from the array of employees to actually grab the employee object, but I hope this is a last resort kind of thing.

```
//...code
export class CreateJobFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('instance', { static: true }) instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<Employee>();
  click$ = new Subject<Employee>();

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen())
    );
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map((term) =>
        (term === ''
          ? this._employees
          : this._employees.filter(
              (v) =>
                v
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf(term.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
            )
        ).slice(0, 10)
      )
    );
  };
  jobAttributes: [
    number,
    string,
    number,
    number,
    string,
    number,
    string,
    Employee
  ];
  comments: string;
  _employees: Employee[];
  constructor(private _employeeServ: EmployeeService) {
    this.jobAttributes = [null, '', null, null, '', null, '', null];

  }


  onSubmit({
    value,
    valid,
  }: {
    value: [number, string, number, number, string, number, string, Employee];
    valid: boolean;
  }) {
    let temp = <Employee>value[7];
    console.log(typeof temp);
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(value[7].toString());
  }
}
```

Console:

```
{jobAttributes[0]: 123, jobAttributes[1]: "123"...}
jobAttributes[0]: 123
jobAttributes[1]: "123"
jobAttributes[2]: 123
jobAttributes[3]: 123
jobAttributes[4]: "123"
jobAttributes[5]: 123
jobAttributes[6]: "123"
jobAttributes[7]: Employee {firstName: "Hillary", lastName: "White", id: 790335, available: true, signedIn: true}__proto__: Object
create-job-form.component.ts:83 undefined
create-job-form.component.ts:84 undefined
core.js:6237 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: So what's in `jobForm`? Where does that come from?

Comment: First, do a condition before toString: ``` if( v != undefined) {//then here acces to your variable}```

Comment: @Phil  my TS file I have  an attribute called `jobAttribute` which is an array of `[number, string, number, number, string, number string, Employee]`. inside `JobForm` it assigns values through `ngModel` to each value in it's array

Comment: @OAH the issue I am having is that everything returned on the `onSubmit ` call is undefined. However it should be returning an array of `[number, string, number, number, string, number, string, Employee]`. My issue is that I need those values to be defined not `undefined` but in the HTML and console it is defined?

Comment: I noticed what works is that if I iterate through`jobAttributes` on`onSubmit` however `value` is still `undefined`, but the values are assigned through `jobAttributes` I don't think this is the appropriate solution though.

Comment: why just pass jobForm.value into click function

Comment: I am doing it the same as a course I took on Udemy. Their `onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: User; valid: boolean }) {
    if (!valid) {
      console.log('Form is not valid');
    } else {
      value.isActive = true;
      value.registered = new Date();
      value.hide = true;
      this._userService.addUser(value);
      this.form.reset();
    }}` is like this, but mine instead is an array of objects.The weird thing is that `jobAttributes` is filled and `value` when console logged it displays the object and it's values,but when I try to assign or use `value` -it says `undefined`